# Source control with Visual Studio integration for a small project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, version-control, tfs

I'm begining the development of a personal Web Application project. I'd like to have a source control system for that project.

At work, we user Team Foundation Server and I'm quite happy with that, mostly for the Visual Studio integration.

I'd like to know if there was **free** source control solutions that had the same kind of integration with VS2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just started using Subversion actually, all I did was go to their website and download the server (took like 10 mins to install and setup). The installer asks you where you want your code repository to be and then it sets up the server completely. The only thing I had to do was put in a password file. I installed ankhsvn (which is an SVN client that integrates into Visual Studio) and it worked perfectly, without a hitch. Exactly how you'd expect. It's very little work overall.

Answer (score 2):

[subversion](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/), [mercurial](http://sharesource.org/project/visualhg/)

Answer (score 2):

I think you have two options, really:

Subversion. It's easy to setup etc, and free. I like VisualSVN, which is $50, and worth atleast 5x that much, but you can use Ankh (free, OSS) or just use tortose (windows explorer plugin, OSS, free).

Once you have tortoseSVN (VisualSVN needs it too) you can make local repo's, or use a remote one, eg VisualSVNServer (also free), or personally, I have mine hosted with my websites at dreamhost :)

Another option is [SourceGear Vault](http://sourcegear.com/vault/). It's GREAT if you have a windows-based server somewhere (it's SQL 200x + ASP.NET based, including SQL Express Edition I think), and it's free for one user. Very good if you are used to SourceSafe or TFS, and it can work in the SVN/CVS checkout-merge-commit way if you want to (not the default, but easy to change), or just use the check out - lock - check in way like VSS.

You might have heard Eric Sink of SourceGear on the Stack OVerflow podcast the other week - same company.

Answer (score 1):

[50 Bucks](http://www.visualsvn.com/) gets you all the subversion control you could need.

EDIT:  And in the long run...50 bucks is as good as free...

Comment: (50$ + closed source on top of really free (tortoisesvn)) != free

Answer (score 1):

I found Subversion very easy to install. AnkhSVN integrates into the Visual Studio IDE nicely and makes sure you don't forget to add new files created in the IDE to SVN. However, AnkhSVN also seems to have it's periodic hiccups.

TortoiseSVN seemed more stable when I used it, plus it has some advanced features (like a nice conflict editor) that Ankh is still lacking. That's why I use both Ankh and SVN for the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion is good, but not that easy to install (since it requires Apatche). Take a look at [Vault](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/) very simple to install, and works very well with Visual Studio. It's also free for single developer.

Comment: visualsvn makes it easy to install just click Next Next Finish

Comment: Subversion doesn't require Apache--you can run it over SSH, or directly on a repository that exists in a local filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

visualsvn + ankhsvn works great for me

Answer (score 0):

I have had good experiences with [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) although it does not integrate directly into Visual Studio. It is free and integrates into Windows quite well.

If you want a solution that has more integration I would recommend Vault from [SourceGear](http://www.sourcegear.com/vault/). It is free for individual users and is easy to setup. It has more features than SVN and direct access from within VS.